# Automate push to github in laravel project

Tags: php, git, laravel-5, github

I'm trying to add, commit & push to github using php code from Laravel controller using:

```
shell_exec('git add . && git commit -m "Nero" && git push origin master');
system('git add . && git commit -m "Nero" && git push origin master');
```

1. The code added files changed successfully.
2. The code commit successfully.
3. It takes too long time and still didn't push the code.

I tried a lot of commands and it successfully run, the problem is in

```
git push

git push origin master
```

Comment: Do you have an error message ?

Comment: at first I got no response for long time then I got "Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded" so I increased the execution time but I still didn't have a response

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your git credentials are correctly configured? My guess is that the push command is waiting for you to enter your Github username/password.

You could verify by getting the shell_exec output like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('git add . && git commit -m "Nero" && git push origin master');
```